# How do Cloud Credits work?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

How do cloud credits work?

In the documentation, it says that `CloudDeploy[]` uses CloudCredits (http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/cloud-deployment/).

However, I tried to call:

```
$CloudCreditsAvailable
Loop[n_] := (For[i = 0, i < n, i++]; i)
CloudDeploy[FormPage[{"n" -> "Integer"}, Loop@#n &]]
```

If I understand correctly, any usage of the link that appears after this should drain my cloud credits substantially. I clicked the link a few times and inserted ridiculously large numbers but `$CloudCreditsAvailable` still gives me the same result. Also, I am really not sure what 'account' Mathematica uses when I call this function. Is there a way to see that?

### Edit

Today I have about 2000 fewer cloud credits but I can't find any overview about what actually drained those. I played around quite a bit with `CLoudDeploy[]` so I don't know what used credits and what not.

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109259/5467)