# Best Wolfram tool for interactive web-based calculator

Tags: webmathematica, cloud-deploy

A colleague is considering re-implementing this online ["Photon Propulsion Calculator"](http://www.deepspace.ucsb.edu/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Laser-Propulsion-Classical-1D-Standalone.html) using a Mathematica-based product. I wanted to ask the community which product would be best.

- **WebMathematica**

  - Runs locally on our servers (good)
  - Requires client enables Java / Flash, which browsers are moving away from.
  - Not many "webmathematica" tags on Mathematica StackExchange & Wolfram Community  -- maybe hard to get help.
  - Not many updates since MMA 8, see [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/webMathematica/tutorial/NewFeatures.html#50513800).
- **Mathematica / CloudDeploy[]**

  - Develop the GUI in MMA, then CloudDeploy it
  - Easy to develop locally (in MMA)
  - Costs Cloud-credits
- **Mathematica Online / Programming Lab**

  - Users would see a Mathematica-like environment in their browser
  - Users would have to at least know how to shift-enter to execute it?
- **Wolfram|Alpha Simple API**

  - Not a tool for building interactive user-interfaces
- **CDF**

  - Have users download the CDF and the CDF player, and run it locally.
  - Seems abandoned in favor of cloud-based stuff.

[This link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109231/current-e-g-ca-2016-mma-10-wp-4-best-practices-for-embedding-interacti) from 2016 suggests that cloud stuff is the wave of the future, but I wanted to see if WebMathematica had a chance.

Thoughts?

Comment: Which would be the best for what? What is the background, just a widely accessible web tool? Commercial tool? Does it need to be as smooth as the linked example? All details matter.

Comment: `Requires client enables Java / Flash,` I had no idea that WebMathematica needs one to install Java on Browser to use it!  This is definitely a show stopper. Java in browser these days? Is this even possible to do now? I have always thought WebMathematica does not need Java on client side.  I was wrong.

Comment: @Kuba, you are correct that the calculator is a non-commercial widely-accessible web tool. As I understand it, this porting effort is mainly to convert the Calculator into a form that is easier for undergraduate physics  students to maintain (Mathematica instead of Javascript).

Comment: @Nasser, re: webMMA needing Java, I inferred that from the Web MMA Q&A  [here](https://www.wolfram.com/products/webmathematica/qa/): "Administrators of a webMathematica-based site must be able to maintain a Java Servlet site." Also: "Using the Java applet LiveGraphics3D, you can create and manipulate three-dimensional graphics interactively in your web browser."

Comment: @Nasser No Java in a browser is needed to run webMathematica, except you really want to use LiveGraphics3D (which is not supported anymore).

Comment: @ConvexMartian Why do you think CDF is abandoned? It is alive and kicking and up to date (11.0.1) and I am sure the great WRI-folks will release the CDF-Player for 11.1 this time maybe at the same time as the full 11.1 version

Comment: @ConvexMartian I would write a CDF and build it in such a way that you can CloudDeploy it, and it will probably just work, but maybe not with the same response time. The interesting question is: why does your colleauge want to use Mathematica? More flexibility?

Comment: @RolfMertig, thanks for your thoughts. My impression of CDF came mainly from [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109231/current-e-g-ca-2016-mma-10-wp-4-best-practices-for-embedding-interacti). MMA is appealing because so many undergraduate and graduate students use it in the physics department in my university. MMA seems more long-term stable than whatever hot web-dev platform the kids are using these days.

Comment: So the solution should not require the author of the tool to know anything more than Wolfram products? So no JS/Css knowledge is assumed?

Comment: @Kuba, let's assume some knowledge of JS/CSS. Assume the author is an eager undergraduate physics student with a little programming experience in JS / CSS / MMA.